# Dynamically apply search filter in Jquery on multiple search boxes on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple search input box on same page with different list in it that I want to search.

My issue is when I search in one search box it applies to all others, and all others are also searched. I want it specific to the field that user searches

Here is the fiddle link:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EFTZR/146/)

HTML

```
<ul id="category1">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>item27</li>
    <li>item28</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

        var searchText = $(this).val();

        $('ul > li').each(function(){

            var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
                showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

            $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        });     
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your input an ID, and attache the handler to it: http://jsfiddle.net/o88bbdkv/1/

```
$(function(){

  $('#searchInput').keyup(function(){

    var searchText = $(this).val();

    $('ul > li').each(function(){

        var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
            showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

        $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

    });     
  });

});
```

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" />

<ul id="category1">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>item27</li>
  <li>item28</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I already used id and checked but not working updated http://jsfiddle.net/o88bbdkv/5/

Comment: you need to tell which ul you need to filter, at the moment you are filtering every li on the page....

Use the ID you have given to the UL - updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8y98Lj4c/

Comment: Heyya is there a way by which we can optimise it more and have just one function to dynamically take up the ids or so????

Comment: Of course, but you should really investigate and learn how to do this, if you get stuck, post your code and we can help you out :)